# How to replace negative values with 0 in Cumulative sum calculation in Tableau?

Tags: cumulative-sum, tableau-desktop

I have to replace the negative values with 0 in Running sum field.

I have created a calculation, like this

IF SUM([Sales]) < 0 THEN 0
ELSE  RUNNING_SUM(SUM([Sales]))
END

Table calculation using "Across".
But I am not getting expected result.

[image]

I should get the results like this:
[image]

Comment: You can simplify the expression slightly as RUNNING_SUM(MAX(0, SUM([Sales])). And you also need to set the partitioning/addressing aka "compute using" settings as desired, just as for any table calc.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, calculate ***Down*** the table rather than ***Across***  it.

See [how to transform Table Calculations](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations.htm#table-down) in the Tableau Documentation.

Also see the [Running Sum Calculation Documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_runningtotal.htm#running-total-calculation).